# Solvable group, primitive group action

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, solvable-groups

> Let $G$ be a group which acts primitively on $X$. When $G$ is solvable and $|X|=n$, then $n$ is a prime power.

Hello,

I have a question to this task.
As a hint is given, to show, that every minimal normal subgroup is elemantary abelian.
Therefore abelian and every non-trivial element has order $p$.
Then use:

> Let $G$ be a group which acts transitively on $X$. If the action is primitive and $N\unlhd G$, then $N$ is transitive or in the kernel of the action.

Showing that the minimal subgroup is abelian is easy:

Since $G$ is solvable, $N$ is solvable. Since $N$ is minimal $N/\{e\}\cong N$ is abelian.

Now I want to show, that every non-trivial element has order $p$ (where $p$ is prime of course).
But I am stuck.

My try was to take $N\ni x\neq e$ and observe $\langle x\rangle$. 
But since $N$ is minimal it has to be $\langle x\rangle=\{e\}$.

I wanted to use the Lagrange theorem.

Can you give me a hint?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you mean "every minimal normal subgroup is elementary abelian". That is true in every solvable group. Minimal subgroups of finite groups have prime order, so they are obviously elementary abelian.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I edit that. Thank you. But my group does not have to be finite, or is it because $G$ acts on a finite set?

Comment: Yes, the question is about the image of the action on $X$, which is isomorphic to the finite group $G/K$, where $K$ is the kernel of the action, so it is really about a finite solvable group. It is the minimal normal subgroups of $G/K$ that are relevant here.

Comment: So my proof, that $N$ is abelian does not apply here? I have to take a minimal normal subgroup of $G/K$, where I can not conclude that it is solvable, since $G/K$ has not to be solvable?

Comment: You are assuming that $G$ is solvable, so $G/K$ is also solvable.

Comment: Can you give me a direction on how to show, that the elements have order $p$?

Comment: If not then the elements of order $p$ would form a smaller normal subgroup.

Comment: But why? You cant apply lagrange here, can you? Since lagrange does not say that there is a subgroup for every order that divides $n$.

Comment: A minimal normal subgroup of a solvable group is abelian.  I think that's enough hints from me!

Comment: Hmm, but that is what I knew before. How does the fact, that the group is abelian count here?

Comment: In an abelian group $N$,  the set $\{ g  \in N: g^p=1 \}$ is a subgroup of $N$. That is definitely my last comment.